# Run preseed commands as specific user / switching users

Tags: debian, sudo, preseed

Beside the usual setup where I create a normal user `foo`, I want to run a few
`d-i preseed/late_command` commands as that `foo` user.

My initial thought was to simply call those commands with `sudo`, e.g:
`d-i preseed/late_command in-target echo "<pwd>" | sudo -Si <command>`.
This works for some sort of commands. However the problem is that some of the commands load up shell scripts which require to **not** be run with sudo.

Issuing a `su -c "<command>"` would be an alternative, but `su` does not offer the possibility to read the password from `stdin`.

Is it safe to jump around between the users using `su` (And if yes, how do I provide the stdin? and does it work or just result in a `su: must be run from a terminal`) or would this cause issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe consider looking into the "expect" command.

```
expect - programmed dialogue with interactive programs
```

It will allow you to send a password to su. It should work from d-i preseed/late_command.